# 3D chat software crash

Tags: crash, flash-player, runtime-error

One 3D chat software is crashing in Windows 10.

While checking the log, I got this line:

```
flashPlayerTrust directory probably already exists - os.makedirs exception: WindowsError(183, 'Cannot create a file when that file already exists')
```

What does this mean? Can this be the reason for crashing? If so, what's the solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://superuser.com/q/1484001/302907

Answer (score 0):

> What does this mean?

It (apparently) means that the program tried to create a directory which already existed, which caused an error.

> Can this be the reason for crashing?

It's certainly possible.

> If so, whats the solution?

To ignore any existing directories, rather than erroring out. Otherwise, ensure the offending directory doesn't already exist before the program attempts to create it.