# 3D chat software crash error

Tags: crash, windows-task-scheduler, runtime-error

One 3D chat software is crashing in Windows 10.

While checking the log, I got this line:

```
TaskScheduler.pyo(292)   ERROR: Going to bubble out of event pump
```

What does this mean? Can this be the reason for crashing? If so, what's the solution?

Comment: Check event viewer for a app crash log there, it may have more info.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://superuser.com/q/1483404/302907

Answer (score 1):

> What does this mean?

If I am not mistaken, it seems to indicate that the program is attempting to [propagate a DOM event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616694/3395469) which is  going to be passed out of the current event handling loop (pump).

> Can this be the reason for crashing?

It's certainly possible.

> If so, what's the solution?

JavaScript has  `event.stopPropagation()`, but unfortunately I couldn't say whether something similar exists in Python (or whatever code `TaskScheduler.pyo` used).

Answer (score 1):

> What does this mean?

That there is a bug in the program.

> Can this be the reason for crashing?

Maybe.

> If so, what's the solution?

Report this bug to the developers of the application.